# Use python Time travel pattern/antipattern to produce C code

Tags: python

I'm looking for a time travel pattern in python.

I would like to be able to execute a piece of code with variables which will perhaps be changed later in the execution, and if they are changed later in the execution then the previous execution should be different.

Here is a non-working example:

```
def foo(vars):
    aIsHere = False
    bIsHere = False
    if aIsHere:
        print "int a = 0;"
    if bIsHere:
        print "int b = 0;"
    for var in vars:
        if var == "a":
            aIsHere = True
        if var == "b":
            bIsHere = True
        print "%s++;"%var
```

I would like this code to produce valid C.

I know there are many solutions for this specific case, but I would like a pattern for a general case where code that is written before is executed before other code that is later, but with some variables that come from the code after.

More precisely, I want

1. "int a = 0;" and "int b = 0;" before any "x++;",
2. loop through vars once in foo
3. have "int a = 0;" if and only if "a" is in vars, and have "int b = 0;" if and only if "b" is in vars

Comment: If there was a time travel module for python, I would rather scrape tomorrow's stock market data.

Comment: Why do you want to do it like this? You can get the same output that I think you're implying with this code, without fancy time travel code :).

Comment: There are many [text template modules in Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating), because people have different ideas of how to go about it and how much automation is needed.  The most common usage is to insert some text or numbers into a big hunk of fixed HTML to create a web page, but they can be more complicated than that.  One could use this same technique to have python write a C program.

Comment: If, he thought to himself, such a machine is a virtual impossibility, it must have finite improbability. So all I have to do in order to make one is to work out how exactly improbable it is, feed that figure into the finite improbability generator, give it a fresh cup of really hot tea... and turn it on!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it like that? You can get the same output that I think you're implying with that code, without fancy time travel code :).

```
def foo(vars):
    if 'a' in vars:
        print "int a = 0;"
        print "a++;"

    if 'b' in vars:
        print "int b = 0;"
        print "b++;"
```

Comment: Seriously, this is really about when `foo()` or other templates are called.  He should only call it when the `vars` are finalized and not before.

Comment: The code above is a simple example. In my actual case vars is a complicated tree structure which I have to traverse, and "a++;" and "b++;" are many complicated nested if statements (that (possibly) use "a" and "b"). I am trying to avoid traversing the vars structure twice and I would like a generic way to do it, not specific to my case.